# How can I increase internet speed

Tags: internet

I use Ubuntu 11.10, and I connect internet via a ethernet card.

I have problem about very slow internet speeds. The manager at my work place tried to slow down the internet speed but when I use Windows with some download manager the internet speed is really good enough or when I test the speed of internet my results are good.

How can I do? Could you help me please?

Comment: What speeds are you getting and what would expect normally? Have you tried using a download manager in Ubuntu?

Comment: It will help to have more info about your hardware, as it could be a problem related to drivers.